# Is there a way to make generated enum implement a custom interface in Protobuf v3?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protoc, protocol-buffers-3

I would like to have the generated enum in Proto3 implement a custom pre-existing interface, as follows:

```
public enum GeneratedProtoEnum
      implements CustomInterface, com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum {

    // ...
}
```

(by default, enum implements only `com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum`).

For messages, the similar functionality can be achieved with the `message_implements:` insertion point.

But there is no such alternative for `enum`-s.

Is there a conventional way to achieve this in Protobuf? Or, possibly, a non-conventional way?